# Usage of "this" in Thread constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, this

Could someone explain me what is the meaning of **"this"** in this line **"th = new Thread( this, name);"** of the following program? The Thread constructor currently used is Thread(Runnable threadOb, String name). Why do I have to use the word "this" in the above expression? For example, in case I write *"th = new Thread( newOb, name);"*, eclipse mentions ob cannot be resolved to a variable. Do I always have to use "this" in this case, and if so, why?
Many thanks in advance.

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
    int count;
    Thread th;

    MyThread(String name){
        th = new Thread( newOb, name);
        count =0;
        th.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println(th.getName() + " starting ");
        try{
            do{
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println(" in " + th.getName() + " count is " + count);
                count++;
            }while(count<5);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(th.getName() + " terminating");
    }
}
public class UseThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("main thread");

        MyThread mt = new MyThread("thread1");

        do{
            System.out.println(".");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }while(mt.count!=5);

        System.out.println("main thread terminating ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you fully understand what `this` means: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: It would be more intuitive if your code example actually used `this` and not `newOb`.

Comment: What I am missing here in the above program, is what this refers to. Since the form of the constructor is Thread(Runnable ob, String name), this refers to a Runnable type object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` represents the *current* object in the *curent* context. `this` can change based on context. For example in the `run()` method if you create and instantiate an anonymous inner class, then inside that class, `this` will be different from the `this` in `run()` method.

**Why use this when a `Runnable` object is expected?.**
You have :

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
```

So, in `MyThread(String name)` , this will be the current instance of `MyThread`.
Since `MyThread` implements `Runnable`, All `MyThread` instances are also `Runnable`s, so, this can be used instead of an instance of `Runnable`

Example :

```
SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
obj.doSomething();


private void doSomething(){
// here this is implicitly set to obj i.e, the calling object
}
```